# NavDirections arguments in wrong order

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm using the Android Jetpack Navigation component, and it seems like it's requiring that I pass the arguments in the wrong order.

I have two fragments (fragment1 and fragment2).  Fragment 2 takes four arguments (bool, string, int, CustomParslableClass?).  The IDE thinks that that is the correct order (and shows the red squiggles with a message "Type mismatch [...]" if I don't have them in that order).  The app *used* to build fine with that order (a year ago when I last worked on it), but today I downloaded everything and had to update dependencies to build.

This is the normal line of code that the IDE thinks is right (used to work):

```kotlin
val direction = HomeViewPagerFragmentDirections.actionFragment1ToFragment2(false, "Favorites", 17, null)
```

However, when I **build** with that order, I get build errors for each argument:

```
e: filename.kt: (51, 106): The boolean literal does not conform to the expected type String
e: filename.kt: (51, 112): Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Int was expected
e: filename.kt: (51, 125): Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but PlaylistEntry? was expected
e: filename.kt: (51, 136): Null can not be a value of a non-null type Boolean
```

On the contrary, when I re-order the arguments to the function like so (arg2, arg3, arg4, arg1):

```kotlin
val direction = HomeViewPagerFragmentDirections.actionFragment1ToFragment2("Favorites", 17, null, false)
```

it builds fine, but the IDE shows red underlines under each argument, saying they're in the wrong order!  (`Type mismatch. Required: Boolean, Found: String`)

---

Maybe important:

- arg1 (bool) has a default value of false
- arg2 (string) has no default value
- arg3 (int) has no default value
- arg4 (CustomParslableClass?) has no default value (but is nullable)

When I change arg2 to have a default value, the IDE expects the same, but the order that works for build changes to `(arg3, arg4, arg1, arg2)`.

---

A simple clean and rebuild didn't help. I also tried cleaning the project, shutting down Android Studio and restarting, then doing a build.  I even tried deleting the action between the two fragments, and re-creating (building between times).  All to no avail.  Note that when I run the built app, everything works as it should  Normally that would be fine, but I don't think the argument order is supposed to be jumping around like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multi args you should set like below

```
val action = BlankFragmentDirections.actionBlankFragmentToSecondFragment()
        action.arg1 = 2
        action.arg2 = 3
        action.arg3 = "423"
        findNavController().navigate(action)
```

Comment: This doesn't work when you have non-nullable arguments without default values

Comment: Happened when i updated nav component lib, no way i am refactoring whole project to named args